# List containing another list

Tags: java

I have an object in my application, Customer, that has a list of customers.

```
public class CustomerList
{
private List<Customer>
}
```

The customer class in turn has a list of all the items they have shopped at a store on a given day of the week.

```
 public class Customer
{
private List<String> itemsOnMonday;
private List<String> itemsOnTuesday;
private List<String> itemsOnWednesday;
private List<String> itemsOnThursday;
private List<String> itemsOnFriday;
}
```

Now, I want to get the list of all the items the customer has shopped in a given week. What is the best way to do this? My colleague suggests I create another list, and add items to this list. I am not convinced this is a good approach. I have over 1000 customers, and each customer shops over 500 items/week. He suggests something like this -

```
for(Customer customer:customerList)
{
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.addAll(itemsOnMonday);
//So on until Friday.
}
```

This is crazy, because I would end up creating over 1000 objects inside the for loop. Any thoughts on a better way to do this? We have been brain storming for a while now, and can't come up with an efficient implementation to achieve this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't sound crazy at all.  You're not creating _any_ new objects (other than your new lists).  You're just creating new lists that point to the same objects.  What _is_ kinda crazy is having 5 different lists (one for each day) in stead of one map with 5 buckets.  You can read about maps [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: I would start with creating a separate class for `ItemPurchased`, and use just a single list instead of 5 different list for each day. Probably store weekday information in `ItemPurchased` itself.

Comment: @jahroy - We haven't created 7 different lists because we want to. We are getting the data from a JSON string, which contains items as arrays :(

Comment: Back to basics. What are you trying to achieve with this?  If you're trying to get some sort of reports out you're probably best to stick with keeping the information in a database and use BI tools over it.

Comment: The `ArrayList` initialization needs to happen outside the loop. A slight efficiency improvement over what you have here is to create the `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of the sum of all the list sizes. This would prevent it from having to spend time auto-expanding as all the needed space would already be allocated, and the memory efficiency would improve since there is only one back end array created, instead of multiple ones involved in acquiring new space.

Comment: jpmc26 - Happen outside the loop? Are you sure? You mean List<String> list=null; Inside the for loop, list=new ArrayList<String>. Are you sure?

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking that the loop was over items. Sorry. Ignore that part. Still, you could initialize with the capacity.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Read Thilo's comment in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913712/how-jvm-handles-creating-object-inside-a-loop. I am honestly not a java person. You'd have a better answer. I have a bachelors in english literature, and started working at my friend's company a week ago ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and an [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for `Customer`'s items:

```
public static enum Weekday { 
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}

public class Customer {
    private Multimap<WeekDay, String> items = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    // getters, setters etc
}
```

then:

```
// monday items:
customer.getItems().get(Weekday.MONDAY);

// week items:
customer.getItems().values();
```

Comment: Or without Guava: `Map<WeekDay, List<String>>`

Comment: Yep you can do with `Map<WeekDay, List<String>>` but access to week items is less direct ;)

Comment: @RC - I like your idea. Let me check with my colleague on what he thinks ;) Thanks so much.

Comment: For what it's worth, guava also has a [`concat`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat%28java.util.Iterator...%29) method for iterators.

Comment: One follow up question here. If lets say I create a static method that populates the data, what do I mark the method return type? What I mean is - if I have public static List<String> getListOfItems(){for(Customer customer:customerList)
{
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.addAll(itemsOnMonday);
//So on until Friday.
}, how do I return this list object back to the method, since its declared inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Present days of week as an enum and use [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) class for storing lists of bought items:

```
EnumMap<Weeekday, List<String>> boughtItems;
```